# Quantum algortihm for SVD and eigendecompostion

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-phase-estimation

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05404) by Rebentrost, Steffens, and Lloyd, it is stated that:

> Such tasks [eigen- and singular value decomposition of a matrix] could be performed efficiently via phase estimation on a universal quantum computer, as long as the matrix can be simulated (exponentiated) efficiently and controllably as a Hamiltonian acting on a quantum state.

Is there a paper that presents a quantum algorithm for computing the singular value decomposition of a matrix along with its complexity? I know using phase estimation to find the prime factors of an $L$-bit integer has complexity $O(L^3)$ but am unsure if singular value decomposition using phase estimation has the same complexity for an $L\times L$ matrix.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  I edited your question to (1) link to the abstract rather than the PDF, as this can help save bandwidth, (2) listing the authors, which may help later on for searching, (3) formatting the math.

Comment: As to your question I think a quantum algorithm for factoring an $L$-bit number takes time roughly $O(L^3)$ (actually $O(L^2)$, but the number itself is roughly $2^L$.  By the same token I think the Rebentrost, Steffens, and Lloyd algorithm proposes to find the singular value decomposition of a non-sparse matrix of size $2^L\times 2^L$.  [Usually we like to use $n$ for the small number and $N=2^n$ for the bigger number, so we can say that the size of the matrix in the [RSL] algorithm is $N\times N$, but it only uses $O(\mathrm{poly}\: n)$ qubits.]

Comment: @MarkS thanks for the reply! I'm actually trying to find a paper on SVD for general matrices (sparse and non-sparse). I'm mainly trying to figure out if there exists a quantum algorithm for SVD that has complexity better than classical SVD algorithms which are $O(n^3)$ for $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: You can review the quantum principle component analysis paper of Lloyd, Mohseni, and Rebenfrost [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0401). But before you do that, almost all such approaches will rely on the "HHL" algorithm - that might be a good starting point to begin to study.  This website has many such questions related to HHL, and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm_for_linear_systems_of_equations) is also pretty good.

Comment: great, thanks for the refs